# How to limit the number of threads in a workload intensive @MessageDriven context?

Tags: jakarta-ee, apache-tomee

I have a MessageListener which is annotated with `@MessageDriven`. The work that it does is very resources intensive, so I want to limit the number of threads which might execute it simultaneously.

Is there an annotation I can provide to it so that the number of threads is limited? I thought about `@Singleton`, but this just means that a single instance is created but multiple threads might execute against it simultaneously.

Is a better approach to spin up a worker thread at startup which just polls the queue when it's free to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the `maxSessions` activation property governs this. So you can just annotate your MDB similar to the following:

```
@MessageDriven(
  activationConfig = {
    @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destinationType",
      propertyValue = "javax.jms.Queue"),
    @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destination",
      propertyValue = "inbox"),
    @ActivationProperty(propertyName = "maxSessions",
      propertyValue = "1")
  }
)
public class SharedResourceWorker implements MessageListener
```